# php artisan error when push code to Local git Azure

Tags: php, laravel, azure, cicd

**PHP: 7.4.xx**

**Laravel: 8**

**Azure App services Deployment Center uses Local git**

I'm setting up CI/CD for my Laravel project to Azure app service. I got the issue when try to push the code to Azure Local git.

Almost the php artisan code that I put in composer.json file post-install-cmd will get the error:

```
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

[image]

The error log file from Azure:
[image]

But when I remove

```
"post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
```

out of composer.json scripts, it works:
[image]

Any idea on this issue please?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't really need to execute `clear-compiled` script, as you immediately cache all assets again by `optimize`. As it not works, just try to remove it and run again

Comment: Try using the full path to PHP and full path to artisan

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of error messages because it cannot be copied, searched, etc.

Comment: Hi @clvrmnky, I posted the error message in the first row already, then I added screenshot. In case you don't see it: Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1

Comment: Hi @apokryfos thank you. I tried with full path but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @PunyFlash maybe my question not clear enough: all the `php artisan [script]` in "post-install-cmd" will get the error, not specific `clear-compiled` or `optimize`

Comment: Are there any hints in the build-debug.log file mentioned?

Comment: @Mít those error messages are not text.